# assert at occcount.cpp 926 line in visual studio 2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, mfc

I have source code based on MFC in visual studio 2008 and Windows 10. When I build as Win 32 debug mode , occured the accert fail at runtime

[show assertion message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBvY6.png)

So I found the solutions to resolve this problem at below link.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/949107/debug-assertion-failed-in-occont.cpp-line-926

But it is not helpful because I don't have the extra dll, or ocx. 
I could find the assertion point. please see the below code.

```
if(m_objSearchDlg.Create(IDD_SEARCH_DLG, (CWnd*)this) == FALSE)
return bResult; 
m_objSearchDlg.ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
```

After m_objSearchDlg was created, occured the assert when calling the "ShowWindow" method.

I thought that m_objSearchDlg instance is not normal.

Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: The dialog suggests to *"press Retry to debug the application"*. That will reveal the call stack and should be your first step in analyzing the issue. I don't know what what *"I don't have the extra dll, or ocx"* is supposed to mean. If you don't have the ActiveX control available, there's nothing you can do. This dialog will fail to display (unless you remove that ActiveX control from it).

Comment: I found the root cause. My sources include the CMSFlexGrid is required the msflxgrd.ocx.